# Не устанавливаются кукис

Tags: php

При авторизации не хочет запоминаться логин с помощью куки, написал все верно, но вот единственная строчка с setcookie('login', $_POST['login'], time()+3600*24*30*12*20); не работает.

```
<?
ob_start();
session_cache_limiter('private');
session_cache_expire(2592000); // 5 лет в минутах / кеширование на 5 лет в сессии
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- Обычный текст -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- Прописной для главн -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes" rel="stylesheet"><!-- Прописной для главн -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/auth.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width = 960, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/auth_process.css">
</head>

<body>
    <?
include '../db.php';
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
try {
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
$stmt->execute();
while ( $row1 = $stmt->fetch() ) {
    $login_in_data = $row1['login'];
    $name_in_data = $row1['name'];
}
} catch (exeption $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); } 

if ( $login == $login_in_data ) {
    setcookie('login', $_POST['login'], time()+3600*24*30*12*20);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT password FROM users WHERE login = (:login) ");
    $stmt->bindParam(':login', $login);
    $stmt->execute();
while ( $row2 = $stmt->fetch() ) {
    $password_in_data = $row2['password'];
}

    if ( password_verify($password,$password_in_data) ) { 
        ?>
        <div class="middle2"> <?
            echo "Вы вошли, как " . $name_in_data;                       //Вошел
            ?>
            <br> <a href="../personalAccount.php">Личный кабинет</a> 

            <? header('Location: ../personalAccount.php'); ?>
        </div>
        <?
        $_SESSION['authorized'] = 1;       // Помечаем, что пользователь авторизован
        $_SESSION['login'] = $login;       //вносим логин в сессию
    } else { 
         echo "<p class='font'>Не правильно введён логин или пароль!</p>"; ?>
        <a href="../auth.php">Вернуться</a>
        <?
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
    }
} else {
?> 
<div class="middle2 font"> 
    <?
    echo "Не правильно введён логин или пароль!";             //Не вошел
    ?>
    <a href="../auth.php">Вернуться</a>

</div>
<?
session_unset();
session_destroy();
}

?>
<? ob_end_flush(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Знаю, что есть косячные моменты, но хотелось бы сначала понять, с чего куки не задаются :р

Comment: да вроде как нельзя выводить что то в браузер перед установкой кук/сессий...

Comment: @sterx как же мне тогда быть? сделать обработчик отдельно?

Comment: @Cool_cool,  данные по авторизации, судя по коду, в кукис/в сессию должны записываться успешно. Я верно понял, что в скрипте personalAccount.php вы не можете получить данные об успешной авторизации? Если это так, то в нем, перед использованием $_SESSION - вы должны стартовать сессиию (session_start())